# MSILO messages to users behind NAT

Tags: kamailio

I am using Kamailio (5.0.1) and MSILO module for offline messages but I have a problem with users behind NAT.
According to module overview, MSILO is forwarding the offline messages to contact address provided in REGISTER request.
Is there any way to overcome this and send the messages to the external client IP?

Answer (score 0):

Set **outbound_proxy** parameter [1] for **msilo** module to you Kamailio address and you get the **MESSAGE** set first to Kamailio, there you can do the usual SIP routing. Skip authentication for requests coming from the local address and then do the location routing for these **MESSAGE** requests.

[1] - https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.2.x/modules/msilo.html#msilo.p.outbound_proxy